# I got different result for same input on junit tests and on Android (ART) at runtime

Tags: android, regex, kotlin, junit, jvm

I have a one static method which finds matching texts on target text, but it returns different results for same input, results in `Junit` tests and result in `Android` at runtime is different.

```
private const val REGEX = "GE[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\\s?([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})([0-9]{2}\\s?)([0-9]{4}\\s?){3}([0-9]{2})\\s?"
private val PATTERN: Pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX, Pattern.MULTILINE or Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)

fun find(text: String): List<String> {
    val textFormatted = text.replace("\\s".toRegex(), "")
    val list = ArrayList<String>()
    val matcher = matcher(textFormatted)
    when {
        matcher.matches() -> {
            list.add(textFormatted)
        }
        matcher.find() -> {
            val partitions = findGroupMatches(matcher)
            list.addAll(partitions)
        }
    }
    return list
}

private fun findGroupMatches(matcher: Matcher): List<String> {
    val partitions = mutableListOf<String>()
    for (i in 0 until matcher.groupCount()) {
        val partition = matcher.group(i)
        if (partition != null && PATTERN.matcher(partition).matches()) {
            partitions.add(partition.replace("\\s".toRegex(), ""))
        }
    }
    return partitions
}
```

And the magic (imho) happens here

```
On JVM tests, it returns emptyList

@Test
fun `find with not valid text returns emptyList`(){
    val targets = PatternUtils.find("GE03TB 7433311450666666300008")
    assertTrue(targets.isEmpty()) // success
}

PatternUtils.find("GE03TB 7433311450666666300008") on Android inside `onCreate()` returns 1 size list("GE03TB743331145066666") //
```

Why it works like that? Is there any bug? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason was that `Pattern.java` implementation by Oracle and by Google are different.

In order to work similarly I had to create new `Matcher` instead of reusing it.  (Matcher.java has some methods with side effect)

```
fun find(text: String): List<String> {
    val textFormatted = text.replace("\\s".toRegex(), "")
    val list = ArrayList<String>()
    val matcher = createMatcher(textFormatted)
    when {
        createMatcher(textFormatted).matches() -> {
            list.add(textFormatted)
        }
        matcher.find() -> {
            val partitions = findGroupMatches(matcher)
            list.addAll(partitions)
        }
    }
    return list
}
```